# Tell me some Http-streaming tutorial or example

Tags: php, javascript, comet, real-time

Could you tell me some http-streaming tutorial or example ( used also by Gmail ) ?

I want to create a simple chat for college project.

Attention: I am talking about Http-streaming and NOT long-polling.

Thanks ;)

Comment: I think you need to be more specific about what you want to do, and what platforms you are using.

Comment: I want to create a simple chat using http-streaming ( not long-polling ) ;)

Comment: I have written a tutorial on [ajax streaming](http://www.codekites.com/ajax-based-streaming-without-polling/) and [sse](http://www.codekites.com/monitor-progress-long-running-php-scripts-html5-server-sent-events/). Check them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [here](http://blog.simonwillison.net/post/57956839764/comet). Some cool intro about Comet. There is also a mention for Jetty and its free chat client but they are in Java not PHP. Will keep looking and post if I find something useful with PHP. Just FYI, jquery has a plugin for comet but I haven't tried it yet.

Comment: jquery has a plugin for long-polling. I need a http-streaming example and not long-polling as I write above ;)

Comment: I suppose http://ajaxian.com/archives/picomet-simple-comet-library?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+ajaxian+%28Ajaxian+Blog%29 should be fine for you.

Comment: Just saw your comment come up. What I know is that long-polling is AJAX, http-streaming is Comet (or server push). Am I getting this wrong?

Comment: So i knew wrong :). Just confirmed from wikipedia. Not sure what technology the other link uses though. It says comet and as I just read Comet is an umbrella term for both http-streaming and long polling. Let me know if you manage to find anything on this.

Answer (score 1):

"Comet" is just an umbrella term that includes HTTP streaming.

For some good examples, you can check out our [WebSync demos](http://www.frozenmountain.com/websync/demos).

For some tutorials on using it, you can check out the [tutorials](http://www.frozenmountain.com/websync/support/tutorials).